# Cannont convert value of type () -> Void

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have been converting over to the new swift syntax. I'm having trouble tweaking a third party SQLITE party into Swift 3.0. It appears there has been an update to closures: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md

I cannont figure out for the life of me how to pass the variable "task" to my function to be added to the GCD queue Here's what my code looks like when I call my function "put on thread."

```
      let foo: ()->Void = {
          let interesting = "confusing"

            print("Swift 3.0 Conversion has been " + interesting + " with some parts!")
        }
     /// Compiler error: Cannot convert value of type () -> Void to expected argument SwiftData
        putOnThread(foo)

    ///I have also tried this and I get a different compiler error: 
         SwiftData.putOnThread(foo)
//Compiler error: Use an instance member 'putOnThread' on type 'SwiftData'. Did you mean to use a value type of SwiftData instead?
```

Here's what the putOnThread method looks like:

```
 extension SwiftData {
       public func putOnThread(closure: @escaping ()->Void) {

    SQLiteDB.sharedInstance.queue.sync {
                    closure()
            }

        }

    }
```

Note: SwiftData is a struct. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Maybe once I'm finished, I can happily commit my Swift 3.0 changes back to github!

Comment: Where are you calling `putOnThread`? It looks like you're trying to call it at static scope, but it's an instance method.

Comment: Yes! You're totally right. I called within a static scope method.

Comment: Do you know http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift ? It's already ready for Swift 3. And so much safer than SwiftData which performs custom (hence doubtful) value escaping instead of proper SQLite value binding (see https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData/blob/master/SwiftData.swift#L1244)